# Filter a specific case using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Say I have the following generic data

```
A <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5)
B <- c(1,1,2,1,2,1,2,3,2,3,3,4,4,3,2,3,3,4,4,5,4,4,5,5,5)
C <- c(1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0)
Data <- data.frame(A,B,C)
```

Then I create the following sunflower plot

library(zoo)

```
Data$F = ifelse(Data$C==1,Data$A,NA)

Data$F = na.locf(Data$F)

Data$G = ifelse(Data$C==1,NA,Data$B)

sunflowerplot(Data$G ~ Data$F,
              main = "Flower_plot", 
              xlab = "B value where C==1",
              ylab = "B value where C==0",
              size = 0.25, cex.lab = 1.3, mgp = c(2.3,1,0))
```

And when we look at the plot, we want to remove some of the data.

We want to remove where for a C=1 and B=3, the data where C=0 and B=4

I have tried something like this

```
library(dplyr)    
Data_cleaned <- Data %>%
      group_by(C) %>%
      filter(rm(B==4[A==3 & C==0]))
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: A new data frame that has specifically removed rows numbered 12 and 13

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Data_cleaned <- Data %>%
  filter(!(B==4 & A==3 & C==0))
```

`!` means `NOT` - negates the results.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know the ! function could be used

Answer (score 3):

`zx8754` answer is good. I'd just add a possible `data.table` solution which will be both fast (binary join) and will allow you to avoid specifying column names if you want to do different subset operation on same columns (`<-` will preserve the key)

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(Data), A, B, C)
Data[!J(3, 4, 0)]
```